# Javascript recursion count forward and backward

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am trying to understand recursion by writing a recursive count function. One variation of the function is to count forward and other backward. I understood the backward one but not the forward one because just by changing order of statements in the else block I am able to count forward.

```
function countforward(num) {
    if (num == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (num == 1) {
        return console.log(1);
    }
    else {
        countforward(num - 1);
        console.log(num);
    }
}


function countbackward(num) {
    if (num == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (num == 1) {
        return console.log(1);
    }
    else {
        console.log(num);
        countbackward(num - 1);
    }
}
```

The backward function is clear to me because every time the control hits the else block first the number is displayed and it is reduced and called again, but i didn't get the forward function

Comment: more indentation, less perfomance ...

Comment: This code doesn't actually work, as `count` isn't defined.

Comment: Where is the recursion? No function is calling itself. They're calling `count()`, which is undefined.

Comment: the line `count(num - 1);` should be `return count(num - 1);`

Comment: @Nina Scholz why should we talk about indentation here?

Comment: it was kind of ironically, kind of a rule of thumb by having too much nested statements, where the compexity of the code is simply measured by looking to the indentation. to overcome this, refactoring is the action of choice. this reemoves indentation aund take codes into own function and makes code more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we wrote a description of what each function does:

- `countforward(n)` prints the values from 1 to n in ascending order
- `countbackward(n)` prints the values from n to 1 in descending order

Placing these descriptions in for the respective recursive calls, we get:

```
else {
    countforward(n-1); // prints the values from 1 to n-1 in ascending order
    console.log(n);    // prints n
}
```

and

```
else {
    console.log(n);     // prints n
    countbackward(n-1); // prints the values from n-1 to 1 in descending order
}
```

which (hopefully) makes things clear.

Comment: sure I edited my code, (it was a typo)but I am having  a hard time to understand the forward function because when i call it with countforward(3), control hits the else block where the first statement reduces it to countforward(2) and below it the console.log statement should print n value which is 3, but i get 1

Comment: countfoward(3) prints 1,2,3 by (calling countforward(2) which prints 1,2 by (calling countforward(1) which prints 1) then prints 2) then prints 3).

Comment: Thank you. I get it now